# How to use CoreData in a class in a SwiftUI way?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have a music app written in `SwiftUI` with some models (`Song`, `Artist`), and manager class (`LibraryManager`) which handles adding new song, generating playlist and serves as a player manager. The structure is like below.

```
class LibraryManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var songs: [Song] = []
    @Published var artists: [Artist] = []
    @Published var albums: [Album] = []

    // Some methods here
}
```

```
// MainApp.swift - used to pass libraryManager into each view
let libraryManager = LibraryManager()
....
ContentView().environmentObject(libraryManager)
```

I recently want to implement CoreData to my app to store my models like `Song`. I don't want to change a lot of existing code, which means I still want to use the existing `LibraryManager` to handle these things. However, I found there is no way of using `@FetchRequest` in `class`. Any solutions? Or could anyone tell me the convention of the usage of CoreData.

Comment: If you want to use CoreData outside of SwiftUI views then use FetchRequest (and other CoreData API) directly, but on update you will need to refresh corresponding views somehow manually.

Comment: Just try saving to file, that's what iTunes did for years and it was fine.